# How to get file size of live video recording in android?

Tags: android, video-capture

How can I get the video file size while recording a video in Android using a `MediaRecorder`?

Answer (score 1):

```
String recVideoPath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + videoRecordedFileName;

File file = new File(recVideoPath);
long fileVideo = file.length();
```

More or less something like the one above.

Comment: i think what you say that is for get the video file size after save the file. but i want to get file size when video recording start till the video  recording stop.

Comment: Put it inside while(video.isPlaying()), something like that.

Answer (score -1):

Put this in a thread, or where ever you are updating the UI

```
currentPosition = (int) mediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition();
yourProgressBar.setProgress(currentPosition);
```

I hope this helps :)