# Is it possible to check the size of video while recording?

Tags: android, video-capture

I have a requirement to create an app in which i want to record video and to stop the recording when the file size exceeds say 10 mb.Is that possible? I know that file size can be checked after saving. But I want to know whether this can be done on run time.Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: This might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10408133/how-to-get-file-size-of-live-video-recording-in-android

Comment: how you are recording video ? using native camera application or your own code ?

Comment: I've never really done this sort of thing, but you might want to check out the File Observer API http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/FileObserver.html

Comment: Hey Jas look at my answer. When your video size will react to 10MB , video recording automatically stop and ask to save or discard

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use below line in when you start intent for video capture.

```
videoCaptureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_SIZE_LIMIT, 10485760L);// 10*1024*1024 = 10MB
```

Comment: Thanks a lot dude!!! :)

Comment: Welcome. Happy to help..!!! :)

Comment: @Jas Hey I debug this code. You can use long value without using "L" so don't worry use dynamic value like `long fileSizeInBytes = fileSizeInMB  * 1024 * 1024;`